# Special characters when import-module in PS 5 after manually reloading 1 function it works, but the Import-Module works in PS 7?

Tags: powershell

Thanks for checking out my question.

I have a weird one which has probably something to do with encoding, but I'd love to know the exact issue.

A function in a private module gave different results in PS5 and PS7.
By checking the code I found the culprit.

When we load the module in PS5 by import-module containing a foreach dotsource import:

```
Foreach ($import in @($Public + $Private)) {
    Try {
            Write-Verbose "Importing $($Import.FullName)"
            . $import.fullname
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Error -Message "Failed to import function $($import.fullname): $_"
    }
}
```

The function I'm talking about has special characters (which are supposed to be BOM characters) in the scriptblock:

- Ã¯Â»Â¿
- Ã¿Ã¾

Then when I reload the function ((Ctrl + A) + F8) manually in my console the characters are shown correctly in the scriptblock:

- ï»¿
- ÿþ

I check the scriptblock via:

```
(Get-Command FunctionName).ScriptBlock
```

I do not have this issue in PS7.
Can anyone tell me what the reason is behind this issue?

Comment: ps5 doesn't recognize utf8 no bom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to be a variable: `$OutputEncoding`

https://baswijdenes.com/how-to-remove-byte-order-mark-with-powershell/#I_think_I_found_the_reason_why_this_is_happening